# Using emergency US passport to leave/enter UK while UKBA is reviewing my visa

Tags: visas, uk, passports, us-citizens, emergencies

I am a US expat living in the UK. I am currently renewing my UK visa, but I need to travel during the process. The [US London Embassy](http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/acs/passports/ukba_or_foreign_embassy.html) says

> If your current U.S. passport is being held by the UK Border Agency or a foreign Embassy for visa processing and you have urgent need of travel, you can apply for an emergency temporary passport. ... As the temporary passport will not have any UK visas, you must contact the UK Border Agency (UKBA) to find out if you can depart the United Kingdom whilst the visa application is being processed without forfeiting the application and, if so, what documentation you need to take with you to legally return to the United Kingdom.

As the UKBA does not provide a free way to find out this information, I was hoping someone might know if it is possible to depart/re-enter the UK on an emergency US passport without forfeiting my current application.

Comment: Skype charges 12c/minute to call the UKBA contact center: http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/aboutus/contact/contactspage/immigration/

Couldn't you get the information there?

Comment: Yep be aware that there are some companies in the UK that charge a premium rate £2/min+ either to relay the call to the national-rate call centre or attempt to provide the info themselves (usually incorrectly). Unless things have changed recently, the real calls were actually handled by a company called [Teleperformance (0117 916 8000)](http://www.teleperformance.co.uk). Try asking for a UKBA team leader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look on the Foreign Commonwealth Office's page at the British High Commission you should find all info like that on there and you'll be able to email somebody I'm sure, I know your talking US Passports but just seem to be quite helpful, I used to have a special passport and the same thing happened to me but I never had to travel so it was fine. Found the number in London and its landline.

http://FCO.GOV.UK Should have all you need to know about UK Official Stuff

Email
fcocorrespondence@fco.gov.uk

General enquiries switchboard
020 7008 1500

Consular assistance
020 7008 1500

Comment: Right. Email them and ask.